# How to add end date (next 5 business day)

Tags: powershell

I would like to know if it is possible to add an end date counting only business day (days of the week).

```
$ReportDate = (Get-Date).toString('MMMM dd, yyyy')
$EndDate = (Get-Date).adddays(5).toString('MMMM dd, yyyy') # i dont know how or if it is possible to count only business day
```

Comment: Is a solution strictly based on days of the week sufficient: If you also need holiday-awareness, things get more difficult.

Comment: 5 businesses days is always a full week. Or? Thus: [.AddWeeks(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.addweeks)

Answer (score 1):

DateTime objects have .DayOfWeek which is an enum.

Expanding five-day weeks into 7-day weeks should work best with integer division. Have a look at `[Math]::DivRem()` for that.

This is basically mapping a base-5 period to a base-7 one. In other words, not too different to converting octal to decimal numbers.

The same methods apply. Integer division (`[Math]::DivRem()`) should help, plus modulo ("%" operator).

Enum values in PS can be accessed using `.value__`, that's two underscores, which turns DayOfWeek's Sunday-to-Saturday enumeration into a numeric range of 0 to 6.

Of course careful application of switch statements should also help. They're just a lot wordier.